# Ambiguous occurence `unsafePerformIO' when installing binary-strict

Tags: haskell, hackage

I'm trying to cabal install binary-strict and I get this error:

```
src/Data/Binary/BitBuilder.hs:205:37:
Ambiguous occurrence `unsafePerformIO'
It could refer to either `Foreign.unsafePerformIO',
                         imported from `Foreign' at src/Data/Binary/BitBuilder.hs:38:1-14
                      or `System.IO.Unsafe.unsafePerformIO',
                         imported from `System.IO.Unsafe' at   src/Data/Binary/BitBuilder.hs:42:26-40
                         (and originally defined in `GHC.IO')
Failed to install binary-strict-0.4.8.1
cabal: Error: some packages failed to install:
binary-strict-0.4.8.1 failed during the building phase. The exception was:
ExitFailure 1
```

I'm running ghc 7.6.3. If it's relevant, I have binary-0.7.2.3 installed too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As written, binary-strict only works for `base >= 4.7`. GHC 7.6.3 uses `base = 4.6.*` so it will not work.  You should file a bug with the maintainer and work around the issue by adding `hiding (unsafePerformIO)` to the `import Foreign` line of the file in question.

Comment: Thanks, maybe I'll install a more recent ghc too.

Answer (score 1):

I only just found out about this. It is now fixed. Also I have listed the git repo in the package details so you can now raise issues and I will know about them. Thanks to Thomas for suggesting the fix.